# How to format tic labels in Gnuplot with custom date/time strings?

Tags: date, time, plot, gnuplot

Is there any possibility in gnuplot to format time-based tic labels with custom functions? I know that I can use the regular format codes like

```
set format x '%Y-%m-%d, %a'
```

In this example the `%a` would print English short names of the weekday. So I wrote a mapping function that could translate the name to German:

```
dow(d) =  \
  (d == 0) ? 'So' : \
  (d == 1) ? 'Mo' : \
  (d == 2) ? 'Di' : \
  (d == 3) ? 'Mi' : \
  (d == 4) ? 'Do' : \
  (d == 5) ? 'Fr' : \
  'Sa'
```

But how can I call this function? The correct format string would be `%w`, but this:

```
set format x '%Y-%m-%d, ' . dow('%w')
```

does not work, because it tries to actually pass the string "%w" to my function. I also know that there's `tm_wday(t)` (where the argument `t` would be an Unix timestamp) which returns the 0-based number of the weekday (which my mapping function needs). But how would I tell `set format x` to take the current tic value (which actually is internally an Unix timestamp when setting `set xdata time`) as an argument to this function?

I'm using the latest gnuplot trunk version, if this is of any relevance (so I can use any feature that currently exists, even if still undocumented).

Comment: Try `set locale "de_DE.utf8"; set format x '%Y-%m-%d, %w'`, calling a function isn't supported.

Comment: @Christoph I'm on Windows, so the POSIX locales are not available. But `show locales` gives `LC_TIME German_Germany.1252`, but this doesn't seem to give the German date names, apparently.

Comment: @Christoph Ok, but setting `set locale 'German_Germany.1252'` explicitly makes it work, even though it seems to be set by default set already. If you write this as an answer I will accept it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `locale` settings determine how numbers and dates in tic labels are formatted, e.g.

```
set locale 'de_DE.utf8'
```

or

```
set locale 'German_Germany.1252'
```

depending on your system.